# webpack module build fails when attempting to upgrade from Babel 6 to Babel 7

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to upgrade our project from Babel 6 to 7. I've made the following changes to package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "webpack": "4.28.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
```

Got rid of `babel-preset-*` and added new `@babel/*` packages. Also, added Jest.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "jest": "24.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.4",
    "webpack": "4.28.4",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
```

Our project uses Babel and Webpack, and we manage Babel configuration through `webpack.config.js`. So, the following changes were made to that file:

*webpack.config.js*

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'env'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'syntax-dynamic-import', 'transform-es2015-destructuring', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
        }
      },
    ]
  }
```

Updated the presets section to use `@babel/react` and `@babel/env`.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/env'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'syntax-dynamic-import', 'transform-es2015-destructuring', 'transform-object-rest-spread']
        }
      },
    ]
  }
```

When I run `webpack --mode development`, webpack throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/entry2.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react' from 'C:\MyApp'
- If you want to resolve "react", use "module:react"
- Did you mean "@babel/react"?
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\MyApp\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:58:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
    at C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7
    at buildRootChain (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:120:22)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:85:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (C:\MyApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:140:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:103)
    at _next (C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:194)
    at C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:5:97)
    at Object.loader (C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:56:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:12)
```

I don't understand why webpack is looking for a `babel-preset-react` module, when I have updated the presets section for babel-loader to use '@babel/react'. Heck, it even asks, "Did you mean @babel/react?" Why, yes -- and that's what I said! Any thoughts?

I grep'd the `node_modules` directory for references to 'babel-preset-react' and got several hits, from packages in our dependencies (not devDependencies) section. But, I would assume that `npm install` would take care of satisfying those packages' dependencies. Am I wrong?

Lastly, what is the 4th line talking about, when it mentions using "module:react"? Is that relevant, here?

Comment: Not sure it this will help too much but it looks like you are mixing babel 6 modules with babel 7 modules in the same app.  You might want to update to use @ versions of babel modules like `@babel/preset-react` https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react.

Also, there is a tool that can help with the upgrade to babel 7 - https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade

Comment: @soundslikeodd Thanks for that link to the upgrade tool. It helped me eliminate possibilities.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I hadn't come across the upgrade tool. Using it helped me to eliminate some mistakes I had introduced into `package.json`, by trying to do the upgrade manually.

However, the error persisted. But, after applying the changes suggested by the upgrade tool, I saw (and removed) the following unnecessary section:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
    ]
  }
```

Having this section is what was causing my compilation errors. Apparently, we were able to run for months with this sitting alongside the config options for webpack and (in blissful ignorance) not experience any issues. After I removed it, everything built fine, with Babel 7, relying solely on the webpack configs.

It would be nice if there were a tool to help optimize configuration (i.e., identify redundancies/conflicts) in projects that use webpack together with Babel. Between .babelrc, package.json and webpack.config.js, there are currently just too many potential pitfalls.

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue using the updgrade tool as mentioned, but what fixed it for me was in my webpack config, the tool didn't detect a necessary change in syntax...

[image]